# I need a simple yet efficient memory allocation algorithm

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I am trying to implement my own memory allocation code which is simple yet efficient. Any idea where I can start from. What algorithm gcc uses?

Comment: On a scale of 1..10, where 1 is the most efficient and 10 is the most simple, where should your code lie?

Comment: I would prefer the simplest at the moment.

Comment: You might like to read [About Memory Allocators](http://www.flounder.com/memory_allocation.htm).

Comment: You should be really sure you need this, first. Even under Windows XP where the standard allocator is said to be as abysmal as it can get, I've never had any _reasonable_ case where alloction was a measurable thing or a problem. When allocation becomes a problem, such as when you do upwards of 5 million allocations per second, the actual problem is not the allocator, it's your code. Do fewer. Plus, many "fast" allocators behave very differently in different situations, and a "better" allocator can quite possibly be slower overall, and in non-obvious ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem that has been examined and implemented hundreds of times; chances are your implementation is going to work in a very specific situation and nowhere else. Before spending an extraordinary amount of time attempting to solve this problem yourself, consider existing implementations that beat gcc's generalized allocation mechanism:

http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html

http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/

You could also review the implementation of GCC / glibc itself by reviewing the source releases:

http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/

Malloc is part of the GNU C Library implementation.

Comment: glibc uses tuned ptmalloc2 = http://www.malloc.de/en/ which itself is based on Doug Lea's malloc aka dlmalloc.

Answer (score 6):

A `malloc` which returns always NULL is conforming to the letter of the standard. So I am suggesting

```
/* always return NULL, following the letter but not the spirit 
   of the standard */
inline void *malloc(size_t sz)
{  errno = ENOMEM;
   return NULL;   }
```

If speed is your main criteria, it is reasonably efficient. I don't claim that it is useful, but you didn't ask for usefulness.

Real `malloc`s are complex, because they try to be useful and efficient. They are often built above existing [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) (like [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), `munmap`  on Linux etc...) and they often try to reuse freed memory. Study e.g. the relevant source code of [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl libc](http://musl-libc.org/)

Answer (score 2):

GCC uses malloc(), as provided by the C library of the target platform. For Linux, you can find the implementation of the malloc in the GNU C library here: http://repo.or.cz/w/glibc.git/blob/HEAD:/malloc/malloc.c

For a general purpose allocator, you're unlikely to do terribly much better, and quite likely something terribly worse, since the default allocator has been tuned over many years for many different usage scenarios.

For some special purpose allocator, then yes it's certainly feasible to beat a general purpose one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a really simple method:

```
// 1 KB of data that can be allocated
#define MAX_DATA 1024

char pointers[MAX_DATA];
int  currentOffset = 0;
int ptrNum = 0;
int sizes[MAX_DATA];

void *malloc(int numBytes)
{
    char *ptr = pointers + currentOffset;

    currentOffset += numBytes;

    if (currentOffset >= MAX_DATA)
        return NULL;

    sizes[ptrNum++] = numBytes;

    return ptr;
}

void free(void *ptr)
{
    currentOffset -= sizes[ptrNum--];
}
```

Note that memory needs to be freed in the order it was allocated for this to work.

Comment: To be precise, it needs to be freed in the reserve order it was allocated.